Issue with visual studio code and node
Today i try to learn react js but i face a issue.In my vs code i cant install anything..like npx create-react-app todoapp .It saw a error like this ($ npx create-react-app cc '"node"' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. )
But i check everything especially path in env variables.Evrything perfect and it work when i put this command in command prompt.what is the real issue ..I stuck here since this afternoon.i didnt get a solution.
I want a solution for my issue for my further studies

Please don't tag a VS Code question with Visual Studio, they are 2 completely different products.

You are probably using Windows right?
Install Node.js and check PATH, as you said, you already checked it. Have you ever tried to restart your computer? Because you need to restart your prompt. Check if you are using command prompt in the Terminal of VSCode here:


when i change the terminal to command prompt it worked
